# Semantic song markup with visual "chord stacking"

Tags: html, css, xhtml, semantic-markup

I am looking for a HTML-based representation for song texts with chords above the syllables, in the following fashion:

```
      Am   C        D     F
There is a house in New Orleans
```

Now, I don't care how exactly the HTML looks like in the end, but there is an important constraint: the purpose is not only display, but also storage in a semantically meaningful representation.  Specifically, the songs are converted from a [LaTeX-based](http://songs.sourceforge.net/songsdoc/songs.html#sec5.3) syntax and should be recoverable in their original form, as well as being readable in HTML and easily processable.  So no fancy structure just for the purpose of presentation, and no JavaScript (yes, I have looked at how UltimateGuitar does it, that is exactly not what I want).  I need every element to have a direct correspondence to some logical part, as in the original format.

On the other hand, this gives me a hard time designing a CSS that presents the stacked chords.  The basic rule is that you have "boxes" consisting of a text part and a chord part, and the width of the whole box should be the maximum of either parts, which each can consist of arbitrarily long text:

```
Am         Cmaj7/G  Am G        F Am/G      E7  F#sus4 A
longstuff  short    multichord  more   end.     e  -   ternal
```

The boxing structure is known in advance, so you can assume it as given:

```
((Am) (longstuff)) 
((Cmaj7/G) (short)) 
((Am G) (multichord))
((F Am/G) (more))
end.
((E7) ())
((F#sus4 A) (e))ternal
```

Note that in the last box, the word is hyphenated to compensate for the two chords on the first syllable.  I fear this makes it very hard for CSS, so it might be represented in a slightly different way, e.g.

```
((F#sus4 A) (e) (ternal))
```

You can come up with alternatives, as long as they still have concise semantic meaning.  Here is what I have come up with so far:

```css
.verse {
    line-height: 3rem;
    font-family: serif;
}

.cbox {
    border: 1px solid;
}

.chord {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(0, -1.1rem);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: monospace;
    user-select: none;
    font-size: large;
}
```

```html
<p class="verse">
    Test
    <span class="cbox"><span class="chord">Abc</span>X</span>
    <span class="cbox"><span class="chord">Abc</span>Xyzwv</span>
    <span class="cbox"><span class="chord">Abc</span>Xyzw</span>abc
    sd
    <br/>
    Test
    <span class="cbox"><span class="chord">Abc De</span>Xy</span>zwv
    sd
    <br/>
    <span class="cbox"><span class="chord">Ab</span>xyz</span>
    <span class="cbox"><span class="chord">Abc#sus4/C</span>Zyzw xyz</span>
    <span class="cbox"><span class="chord">Am</span>xyzw</span>
    <br/>
    <span class="cbox"><span class="chord">D</span>xyz</span>
    <span class="cbox""><span class="chord">E7</span></span>
    two
    <span class="cbox"><span class="chord">E7</span>th</span>ree
</p>
```

The sizes and borders are chosen for debugging.  As you can see, the width of the top (chord) part is not taken into account (because `position: absolute` prevents that).

I have tried some other variants, including this one: `<span class="cbox" data-w="2" data-c="Am">longstuff</span>`, where `data-w` is the number of letters in the chord name to be used in the `min-width` of the span, and `data-c` being put into a `before` pseudo-element, but I still didn't succeed at getting the width right.

For the hyphenation issue, I have no idea at all.

And I will likely be using XHTML, although I guess this won't make much of a difference.

Comment: Does my answer help you at all?

Comment: @Sean Whoah, sorry, I must have missed the notification that someone answered. I will have a look soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using [CSS grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) to help keep things from overlapping.

You can specify a grid template of 1 column and 2 rows, and then use classes to tell the content which row it should fit into. The grid will fill nicely and create implicit new columns as needed. It even will work if you have a series of chords or text in a row, without needing to wrap chord/text pairs in a wrapping element.

For the hyphenation, if possible, I'd add an additional class to syllables that need hyphenation, and then create the hyphens using a pseudo element in CSS.

Here's a working example. Hope this is helpful. This was a fun challenge.

```css
.line {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: start;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  gap: 0 0.6em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.chord {
  grid-row-start: 1;
}
.text {
  grid-row-start: 2;
}
.hyphenated:after {
  content: ' - '
}
```

```html
<span class="line">
  <span class="chord">Am</span>
  <span class="text">longstuff</span>
  <span class="chord">Cmaj7/G</span>
  <span class="text">short</span>
  <span class="chord">Am G</span>
  <span class="text">multichord</span>
  <span class="chord">F Am/G</span>
  <span class="text">more</span>
  <span class="text">end.</span>
  <span class="chord">E7</span>
  <span class="chord">F#sus4 A</span>
  <span class="text hyphenated">e</span>
  <span class="text">ternal</span>
</span>

<hr>

<p class="verse">
  <span class="line">
    <span class="chord">C</span>
    <span class="text">Frosty the</span>
    <span class="chord">C7</span>
    <span class="text">snowman</span>
  </span>
  <span class="line">
    <span class="text">was a</span>
    <span class="chord">F</span>
    <span class="text">jolly</span>
    <span class="chord">F#dim</span>
    <span class="text">happy</span>
    <span class="chord">C</span>
    <span class="text">soul</span>
    <span class="chord">C7</span>
  </span>
  <span class="line">
    <span class="text">with a</span>
    <span class="chord">F</span>
    <span class="text">corncob</span>
    <span class="chord">F#dim</span>
    <span class="text">pipe and a</span>
    <span class="chord">C</span>
    <span class="text">button</span>
    <span class="chord">A7</span>
    <span class="text">nose</span>
  </span>
  <span class="line">
    <span class="text">and two</span>
    <span class="chord">Dm7</span>
    <span class="text">eyes made</span>
    <span class="chord">G7</span>
    <span class="text">out of</span>
    <span class="chord">C</span>
    <span class="text">coal.</span>
    <span class="chord">C7</span>
  </span>
</p>
```

---

**Edit:** A downside to the above approach is that the content is hard to understand if unstyled.

A *more* semantic approach could be to combine CSS Grid with content defined in custom `data-*` attributes and CSS variable fallbacks. This way the chords stay stored as attributes rather than marked-up text interspersed with the lyrics.

```css
.verse {
  line-height: 2;
}
.lyric {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  line-height: 1;
}
.lyric[data-chord] {
  --chord: attr(data-chord);
}
.lyric:before {
  content: var(--chord, '\00a0');
}
```

```html
<p class="verse">
  <span class="lyric" data-chord="C">Frosty the</span>
  <span class="lyric" data-chord="C7">snowman</span>
  <br>
  <span class="lyric">was a</span>
  <span class="lyric" data-chord="F">jolly</span>
  <span class="lyric" data-chord="F#dim">happy</span>
  <span class="lyric" data-chord="C">soul</span>
  <span class="lyric" data-chord="C7"></span>
  <br>
  <span class="lyric">with a</span>
  <span class="lyric" data-chord="F">corncob</span>
  <span class="lyric" data-chord="F#dim">pipe and a</span>
  <span class="lyric" data-chord="C">button</span>
  <span class="lyric" data-chord="A7">nose</span>
  <br>
  <span class="lyric">and two</span>
  <span class="lyric" data-chord="Dm7">eyes made</span>
  <span class="lyric" data-chord="G7">out of</span>
  <span class="lyric" data-chord="C">coal.</span>
  <span class="lyric" data-chord="C7"></span>
</p>
```

This creates a one-column, two-row, inline grid for each `.lyric` span. The value of `--chord` is set to the value of the `data-chord` property *only on elements that have that property.* It's then used in *all* `.lyric` elements to set the content of the `:before` pseudo-element, with a fallback to a non-breaking space if the variable is undefined. This is important because it pushes the text into the bottom row for `.lyric` spans that don't have a chord, and keeps the text horizontally aligned.

Comment: Grids are precisely the idea I needed. With some tweaking, the second variant behaves like I want it to. Unfortunately, the hyphenation issue is still a problem; determining when a hypen is needed is impossible before rendering, when not using only fixed-width fonts with known width.